# Empty Pop up Error in Qweb Odoo

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, odoo, qweb

Hi I'm having a problem when I want to print a document , it gave me an empty pop up error ,So I can't see where the problem is . I mention that this problem happens only for qweb and with eclipse as a debuggor .

Thank you

[image: POP UP Error]

Comment: As you already mentioned the message is empty, so please add more information like: how is odoo started in eclipse (arguments, ...), which system parameters in odoo are set (web.base.url and report.url can be helpful), is there an error in the server log?

Comment: no message error in the server log , in fact if i deploy the same code on the server or localy without using eclipse as a debogger , the error becomes visible consequently I  can look for it to solve it  .I wonder if the problem is in a missing file or dependency that should display the error but I don't know what is it !